# How can I have the user change the ImageSource for the ImageBrush in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Recently I've been getting into 3D modeling with C#, and I want to create an application that allows for the user to apply a image to the cube. I've tried to create the cube via C# instead of XAMl but that kept throwing stackoverflow exeptions. Is there a way to change the ImageSource and update the WPF display? If so how.

This is what I have so far:

XAML:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Minecraft_Model.BlockMesh"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Minecraft_Model"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="1000">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF323232" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"></GridSplitter>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="z" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,-1,0,0" FontSize="14" Background="White" Width="30"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="y" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,24,0,0" FontSize="14" Background="White" Width="30"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="x" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,49,0,0" FontSize="14" RenderTransformOrigin="0.175,0.51" Background="White" Width="30"/>

    <Slider x:Name="Z" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ElementName=rotate_z, Path= Angle}" Margin="40,-1,0,0" ValueChanged="Z_ValueChanged" Minimum="-100" />
    <Slider x:Name="Y" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ElementName=rotate_y, Path= Angle}" Margin="40,24,0,0" ValueChanged="Y_ValueChanged" Minimum="-100" />
    <Slider x:Name="X" Grid.Column="0" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ElementName=rotate_x, Path= Angle}" Margin="40,49,0,0" ValueChanged="X_ValueChanged" Minimum="-100" />


    <Viewport3D Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 8" LookDirection="0, 0, -3.5" />
            <!--FieldOfView="120"-->
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <Viewport3D.Children>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <!--Установка освещения - прямой свет-->
                    <DirectionalLight Color="White" Direction="-2, -2.5, -2" />
                    <!--<PointLight Color="White" Position="2,2,2" />-->
                    <!--<SpotLight Color="White" Position="1,3,2" Direction="1,-1,-1"
           InnerConeAngle="90" OuterConeAngle="90" Range="4" />-->
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <GeometryModel3D x:Name="Cube">
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,-1,-1 1,-1,-1 -1,1,-1 1,1,-1 
                                                       -1,-1, 1 1,-1, 1 -1,1, 1 1,1,1"
                                
                                            TriangleIndices="0,2,1 1,2,3 4,6,0 2,0,6 
                                                             0,1,4 1,5,4 1,7,5 1,3,7
                                                             4,5,6 7,6,5 2,6,3 3,6,7"
                                            TextureCoordinates="1,1 0,1 1,0 0,0
                                                                0,1 1,1 0,0 1,0"/>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <!--<DiffuseMaterial Brush="LightCoral" AmbientColor="Red" />-->
                            <MaterialGroup>
                                <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Gray"/>
                                <DiffuseMaterial>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        <ImageBrush x:Name="ImageBrush" ImageSource="{Binding Path=imageUrl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <!--<DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/305344" />
                                    </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>-->
                                </DiffuseMaterial>
                            </MaterialGroup>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                    <Transform3DGroup>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotate_xyz" Axis="1 1 1" />
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotate_x" Axis="1 0 0" />
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotate_y" Axis="0 1 0" />
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="rotate_z" Axis="0 0 1" />
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                    </Transform3DGroup>
                </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D.Children>
    </Viewport3D>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
    public partial class BlockMesh : UserControl
{
    public string imageUrl = @"C:\Users\epicg\Desktop\umodel_win32\UmodelExport\ZeroPoint\ZeroPointShell\Game\Effects\Fort_Effects\Textures\Tile\T_Glass_Cracks_M.png";
    public BlockMesh()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Z_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Cube.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), Z.Value));
    }

    private void Y_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Cube.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 1, 0), Y.Value));
    }

    private void X_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Cube.Transform = new RotateTransform3D(new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(1, 0, 0), X.Value));
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: `ImageSource="{Binding Path=imageUrl, Mode=OneWay}"` - Mode=OneWay is redundant, and imageUrl must be a property, not a field. In order to notify the UI when its value changes, the property must fire a change notification, e.g. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: @Clemens I switched from string(s) to BitmapImage(s), But I have a new problem now. Because I have to use a property in order for the texture update to take place, I cant initialize the assigned variable. Is there a way to fix this or not?